# Выбор товаров из определённой категории c помощью sql

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, мне нужно выбрать товары из определённой категории + нужно выбрать цены товара и всё в одном запросе `sql`.
Товары выбрать получается, но не получается добавить условие, чтобы товары выбирались из определённой категории товаров.

```
SELECT wpp.post_title, wpp.guid, wppm1.meta_value as price FROM wp_posts as wpp
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as wppm1
ON (wpp.ID = wppm1.post_id AND wppm1.meta_key = '_price'
AND wppm1.meta_value BETWEEN 11269 AND 165993)
WHERE wpp.post_type = 'product'
AND wpp.post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 2
```

этот запрос работает, но товары выбираются из всех категорий, а нужно из определённой категории.
Пытался фильтровать по категории так:

```
SELECT wpp.ID, wpp.post_title, wpp.guid, wppm1.meta_value as price
FROM wp_posts as wpp
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as wppm1 ON (wpp.ID = wppm1.post_id AND wppm1.meta_key = '_price'
 AND wppm1.meta_value BETWEEN 11269 AND 165993)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as wptr ON wptr.object_id = wpp.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as wptt
ON wptr.term_taxonomy_id = wptt.term_taxonomy_id
AND wptt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
LEFT JOIN wp_terms as wpt
ON wptt.term_id = wpt.term_id
WHERE wpp.post_type = 'product' AND wpt.term_id=130 AND wpp.post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 2
```

т.е. здесь `id` нужной категории = 130
но выборка не работает.
Как правильно выбрать товары из нужной категории?
**P.S.**
кстати этот запрос работает, просто не для всех товаров были проставлены нужные категории в админке :)

**P.S.**

```
$query = array(
    'post_type'      => array('product'),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => POSTS_PER_PAGE,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field'         => 'term_id',
            'terms'         => $currentCat,
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_price',
            'value'   => $data['prices'],
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);
if(!empty($_POST['ids'])){
    $query['post__not_in'] = $_POST['ids'];
}
$products = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'      => array('product'),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    )
);
```

в результате возвращаются только данные из таблицы `wp_posts`, 
другие данные из таблицы `wp_postmeta` в выборке нет.
А мне нужно ещё присоединить к результату цены на выбранные товары

Comment: А почему сплошь LEFT JOIN? тем более что они всё равно все вырождаются в INNER...

Comment: @Akina, если `LEFT` заменить на `INNER` результат не меняется. Согласен,  в `sql` не совсем хорошо разбираюсь, поэтому прошу подсказать как правильно сделать

Comment: Взять реальный запрос, который WC делает в базу для какой-то категории (подсмотреть через Query Monitor), добавить к нему цену

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' 
AND ID IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 212
)
LIMIT 1
```

212 - term_id

Но лучше используйте обычный WP_Query c аргументами term_query и не делайте велосипед

Что касается твоего WP_Query у тебя ошибка в tax_query `'field' => 'id'`

Comment: ,`Но лучше используйте обычный WP_Query c аргументами` , сначала так и делал, но мне нужно добавлять в выборку `sql` цены товаров `_price`, которые находятся в другой таблице, а ведь с помощью `WP_Query` в результате будет возвращены данные только из таблицы `wp_posts`?

Comment: Ничего подобного. WP_Query имеет подзапросы term_query, meta_query и т.д. Посмотрите документацию на wp-kama.ru

Comment: @KAGG Design, дополнил вопрос, подскажите, что делаю не так?

Comment: @KAGG Design, и ещё этот запрос `sql` я делаю через `ajax`, поэтому нужно вернуть результат выборки во фронтенд и обработать, к примеры вернуть массив товаров и в цикле формировать товары с помощью js

Comment: @word попрвил ответ